# UDP sendto() became very low, python

Tags: python, udp, sendto

once i run a .py to send 10000 UDP(lengh is: 110)  using socket sendto(), a server receive about 400 msgs quickly, and later became very slow for more than 10s each msg.

it is weird if i run the .py again, another 400 msgs received quickly.

is there a limit of buffer or UDP problem, for this situation?

yes i got it! UDP is uncertain to destination, continues package jams after 300 msgs. so i have to add time.sleep(0.2) to make it work. Now i'm trying multiple server process for time interval.

Comment: If you send the messages in a tight loop, then yes it might be a buffering problem. It might also be a firewall that's slowing the rate as sending 10000 packets in short succession usually is a sign of a virus or DDOS trojan or similar.

Comment: I don't have an answer yet but I observed the similar issue. Drilling down a little led me to find out that for every sendto() in python we call in a while loop, it does a route lookup every time (strace shows a netlink socket being created and recvmsg being called on it). This whole process slows everything down. This seems to happen only for IPV6 and not for IPV4. I will update as I find out more. C programs do not suffer from such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It might just be that other things are using your network card to send at the same time, and the system can only send 400ish from your application at a time before something else needs to use the NIC. It sounds more like an issue of network usage, than a problem with UDP or something.